# How to populate a select_tag with an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm trying to add a select field that takes its data from an external API call. This data is returned as an array of hashes:

```
[{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}, {"name"=>"NameB", "id"=>"002"}]
```

How can I use this data to construct a select field that looks something like:

```
<select>
  <option value="001"> NameA </option>
  <option value="002"> NameB </option>
</select>
```

EDIT:

Thanks to the suggestions below I've tried the following:

A:

```
<%= select_tag 'model[field]', options_from_collection_for_select(@hash, :id, :name) %>
```

Gives an error:

```
undefined method `name' for {"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}:Hash
```

B:

```
<%= select_tag 'model[field]', options_from_collection_for_select(@hash) %>
```

Fixes the error but generates the wrong markup

```
<option value="{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}"> {"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}</option>
```

So I think my problem is formatting the array of hashes correctly, and I don't know enough about manipulating arrays of hashes to work out how to do this.

Unless I'm looking in completly the worng direction, I think the key to this problem is to reformat the array at the top of this question to give:

```
{"NameA" =>"001", "NameB" =>"002"}
```

Is this even possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Maybe <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824857/rails-creating-a-select-tag-from-a-object-hash> will help?

Comment: thanks @jxpx777, I'd already looked at this. If I use this solution I get `undefined method `last' `. I think my problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Ah, because it's a Hash and the parameters are the methods to call for the value and text for the select. Try options_for_select with @hash.to_a http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Comment: yes, I tried something similar to this as well. While this does solve the error, it doesn't give the right result. I think because `options_for_select` does not expect keys in the hash? How should I handle these keys? The markup looks like this at present `<option value="{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}"> {"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}</option>`. What I'm after is `<option value="001"> NameA </option>`

Comment: Did you add the `.to_a` call? This will create an array of two-element arrays that will correspond to the name and value of the option tags.

Comment: `@hash.to_a` and `@hash` both give the same output. I think because @hash is actually an array of hashes already? I'm a little confused by this problem, so please let me know if I can give more explanation.

Comment: From the API Doc : `options_for_select({ "Basic" => "$20", "Plus" => "$40" }, "$40")
  <option value="$20">Basic</option>\n<option value="$40" selected="selected">Plus</option>` So basically your hash needs to be reformatted like this : { "NameA" => "001", "NameB" => "002" }

Comment: Yes, how to do this when I have no control over how the hash is generated. It comes from an external source

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-invert

Comment: No way you can format it in between ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A better way to do it in only one command:

```
<%= select_tag "model[field]", options_for_select(@array_of_hashes.map { |obj| [obj['name'], obj['id']] }) %>
```

With your example hash:

```
irb> @array_of_hashes = [{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}, {"name"=>"NameB", "id"=>"002"}]
=> [{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}, {"name"=>"NameB", "id"=>"002"}]
irb> @array_of_hashes.map { |obj| [obj['name'], obj['id']] }
=> [["NameA", "001"], ["NameB", "002"]]
```

Answer (score 40):

If you have array of hashes like this:

```
@people = [{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}, {"name"=>"NameB", "id"=>"002"}]
```

You can use [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) helper with [`collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect) method like this:

```
= select_tag "people", options_for_select(@people.collect {|p| [ p['name'], p['id'] ] })
```

And its done :-).

Comment: Thanks Nikos, Can you please include a link todocumentation. would bereally helpful thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to use Hashes in selects, for me is:

The hash:

```
REVISION_TYPES={"S"=>"Stock", "T"=>"Traducción"}
```

In the form:

```
select_tag(:revision_type,options_for_select(REVISION_TYPES.invert.to_a))
```

Comment: Thanks @albert, but the question was about an array of hashes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `options_for_select` for this purpose. It takes a two dimensional Array. You can convert your hash like so:

```
data = [{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}, {"name"=>"NameB", "id"=>"002"}]
data_for_select = data.each { |hash| [hash['name'], hash['id']] }
options_for_select(data_for_select)
```

As a side note to `options_from_collection_for_select`, it is used in combination with objects. It iterates through the objects and sends a message for the label and one for the id.

Comment: thanks @Yves, the `data_for_select` line is not having any effect on the hash. Any other ideas?

Comment: the `.each` should be `.map`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I eventually figured out a solution that works, though it may not be the best.

```
$ @array_of_hashes = [{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}, {"name"=>"NameB", "id"=>"002"}]
=> [{"name"=>"NameA", "id"=>"001"}, {"name"=>"NameB", "id"=>"002"}]
$ @formatted_array_of_hashes = @array_of_hashes.each.map{ |h| { h["name"] => h["id"] }}
=> [{"NameA" => "001"}, {"NameB" => "002"}]
$ @merged_hash = Hash[*@formatted_array_of_hashes.map(&:to_a).flatten]
=> {"NameA" => "001", "NameB" => "002"}
```

I was then able to create a select field

```
<%= select_tag 'model[field]', options_for_select(@merged_hash) %>
```

that generates the correct markup

```
<select>
  <option value="001">NameA</option>
  <option value="002">NameB</option>
</select>
```

A little convoluted, but its working. I welcome any improvements.

Comment: Change your code when you see my answer, the way you did is long and unnecessary!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why, but none of the answers worked for me. maybe because of Rails 5, so I figured it out by myself and I'm happy to share.
It's now pretty but works well.

It's an Array of Hashes from an external API (Pipedrive) that I want to associate with the user's table:

This is in my form:

```
<%= form.collection_select(:id_user_pipedrive, Owner.all_id_name, :id, :name, :include_blank => '') %>
```

And this is in my fake model:

```
UserPipedrive = Struct.new(:id, :name)
def self.all_id_name
  all["data"].map { |d| UserPipedrive.new(d["id"],d["name"]) }
end
```

Hope it helps someone.