# options_from_collection_for_select doesnt accept hash as argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I have a `select_tag` with an `options_from_collection_for_select` that looks like this :

```
<%= select_tag "dash_select", options_from_collection_for_select(session[:user_hotel_list], "id", "name") %>
```

My variable session[:user_hotel_list] is a collection of hashes that looks something like this :

```
[{"id"=>31, "name"=>"Plaze", "contact_mail"=>"plaze@gmail.com", "contact_phone"=>"+33666027414", "address"=>"JDJDJ", "postcode"=>"92200", "city"=>"JDJDJ", "nb_room"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2016-02-26T12:12:39.214Z", "updated_at"=>"2016-02-26T12:12:39.214Z", "auditor_id"=>nil, "account_id"=>48}, {"id"=>30, "name"=>"dndjd", "contact_mail"=>"djdj@gmail.com", "contact_phone"=>"+33666027414", "address"=>"k", "postcode"=>"92200", "city"=>"kk", "nb_room"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2016-02-25T22:27:47.035Z", "updated_at"=>"2016-02-25T22:27:47.035Z", "auditor_id"=>nil, "account_id"=>48}]
```

Unfortunately I get `undefined method`name' for #`

How can I convert my object to a structure that is accepted by rails `options_from_collection_for_select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `options_for_select` and `#collect` to make this a bit easier.

```
<%= select_tag "dash_select", options_for_select(session[:user_hotel_list].collect{|h| [h['name'], h['id']]}) %>
```

That should get you what you are looking for and hopefully save you some time!

Answer was taken from [How to populate a select_tag with an array of hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096126/how-to-populate-a-select-tag-with-an-array-of-hashes).

Comment: Yes I know this works but I also would like to keep selected the last selected item after a page refresh and I read that this is done using the last parameter of the options_from_collection_for_select method

Comment: You can do the same using options_for_select: the second parameter taken is the selected item: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select.

`options_for_select(container, selected = nil) public`